# Button Multiline Typography

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

for me it is not possible to create a Button with Material-Ui in React which has Multiline.

This is My Code:

```
<Button>
<Typography variant="h3">Text1</Typography>
<Typography variant="h5">Text2</Typography>
</Button>
```

Current result:
 `Text1Text2`

I want this:

```
Text1
Text2
```

The first text should be variant=h3 and the second text variant v=5.
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can make the button `display` style as `block` .
and align the text as per your requirement.

Explore Working solution here :
[image: Edit react-select-test (forked)]

```html
<Button style={{ display: "block", textAlign: "left" }}>
        <Typography
          variant="h3"
        >
          Text1
        </Typography>
        <Typography variant="h5">Text2</Typography>
      </Button>
```